# Can I Deploy windows phone apps in my Nokia Lumia 620 Freely

Tags: windows-phone-8

I Have windows phone 8 And I want to Develop apps and Deploy it Freely.is this possible.

Comment: Yes, when you've registered your phone as a developer phone.

Comment: i've registered my phone but when i debug my apps in phone, a error occur "Unable to install application. The maximum number of developer applications on this phone has been reached. Please uninstall a developer application and try again." any one has idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: My idea is to uninstall a developer application and try again.

Comment: I've Uninstalled All the Developer apps but still getting same error msg.

Comment: may i know what is Developer apps....

Comment: my phone is now Developer unlocked but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Ya, max 10 developer app or unsigned apps are allowed to install in your phone.

Comment: I've Uninstalled all the developer app & unsigned apps from the phone but Still getting Same error. now what to do. plz help

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want to do is sideload the apps . For that you need to developer unlock you lumia620 first , which obviously is going to cost you.Please check price for developer unlocking you phone with microsoft.

Other than that it is impossible to load apps freely ,if it is not through App store.

Hope my answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to load any number of unsigned xap files onto a Windows Phone device provided it is fully unlocked (interop unlock).  How you go about getting your device to that state presents a challenge.  So far, only the Samsung ATIV S has been unlocked to that level for Windows Phone 8.

Once you have fully unlocked your phone you effectively have free reign over your device being able to fully access components such as the registry or file system.

Both Samsung and LG have provided back door diagnostic tools on their phones that facilitate making the needed registry changes to completely unlock their phones.  Whether such features are available on other brands has yet to be discovered.

If you are a software developer, you will probably want to get your hands on an ATIV S before they disappear.